# Short Lived Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

Is it possible for a Spring Cloud Task to launch a Spring Cloud Stream (Source, Processor and Sink applications) as a short lived stream and track the stream processing status through the Task Repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [Spring Cloud Data Flow](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.6.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started), you have the option to launch a Task/Batch-job from a Stream and vice-versa. The bi-directional communication is a convenient feature in SCDF.

A Task/Batch-job can emit events to a channel/topic and that can be an input to a Stream in SCDF - see [sample](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/tree/master/spring-cloud-task-samples/task-events).

Likewise, there are a variety of ways you can trigger to launch a Task/Batch-job from a Stream - more details [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.6.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-launch-tasks-from-stream).

To centrally manage and monitor Streams and Tasks, SCDF provides tools to track them from the UI/Shell/APIs individually. The Stream status will be self-contained (available from persistent storage - see [lifecycle](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.6.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-stream-lifecycle)), but it won't be part of Task Repository, though.